# Edit disable submit button

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to edit in css a disabled submit button. This button is disabled if the checkbox is not checked and enable if the checkbox is checked. I can not edit both disabled and enable button. I can not figure it out how should i do.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh79m/2/) you will understand better. `input#btnsubmit[disabled]` is not applyed.

Comment: Have you thought about adding a class to the element when you're disabling the element with JS? And then just style that class.

Comment: I have but i am not that good in jquery or javascript and i dont know how to really do that.

Comment: I was thinking somethig like `if(this.check).addClass('butonsubmit');`

Comment: CSS overrides previous rules, so if [disabled] is the most important one, that should override all of them, it should be the last css defined.

Comment: @Filip See my answer to see how to do what Mitch said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - `true` is not a valid value for `disabled` attribute - it should be either `disabled="disabled"` (for XHTML compatibility) of just `disabled` without value as of HTML5

second of all - you problem happens because you set `background` in the base input css and `background-color` in the `[disabled]` part - the `background` property has precedence - and as long as it wasn't overwritten - it is still applied

use `background` for both and the problem is fixed

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh79m/4/)

Comment: Please note that the disabled selector in CSS doesn't work in IE8 or below, id recommend using a class :)

Comment: Me too :) but even with classes the issue will still happen due to the precedence issue (see http://jsfiddle.net/Dh79m/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#reguli").change(function(){
    $("#btnsubmit").prop("disabled",!this.checked).toggleClass('disabled-button');
});
```

This code will add/remove a class `.disabled-button` that you can style with css. This is also more widely compatible with old browsers.